# JMeter vs Gatling protocol flexibility

Tags: jmeter, protocols, gatling

I read [JMeter vs Gatling](https://www.educba.com/jmeter-vs-gatling/) article and confused over section 9 Flexibility about JMeter:

> Flexibility    It supports only the HTTP protocol.

And Gatling

> It supports HTTP protocol and also a few other protocols as well.

while in introduction it states other protocols for JMeter:

> The different types of services can be tested by using the Apache JMeter tool such as Web Services, HTTP, FTP, JMS, LDAP, generic processes or different TCP connections etc.

What is the HTTP protocol restriction the article is referring to? what are Gatling other protocols that defer it from JMeter?

**EDIT**

Found another discrepancy in section 8 Ease of use, while JMeter describe as

> It is a bit difficult to use.

And Gatling:

> It is easier to use

It states the opposite in conclusion:

> Finally, to conclude JMeter has more number of features and easier to use compared to Gatling.

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK the question is *What is the HTTP protocol restriction in JMeter* BTW I posted a comment but it wasn't published

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter supports multiple protocols:

- HTTP 1.0
- HTTP 1.1
- HTTP 2 with 3rd party plugin
- JMS
- JDBC
- LDAP
- FTP
- SOAP
- UDP with 3rd party plugin
- MQTT with 3rd party plugin
- XMPP with 3rd party plugin
- RTE with 3rd party plugin
- SSH with 3rd party plugin

And it's highly extensible since its architecture is built with plugins in mind, as of now there are at least 73 OSS plugins and more than 10 commercial plugins.

There is no particular HTTP protocol restriction.

I think the blog is just wrong in formulation and considering all the other errors in it, I am not sure it is worth reading or trusting what is written.

As examples of errors or false statements:

- it says JMeter has no dashboard which is wrong since it has the [HTML report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which contains 17 graphs and 4 tables since version 3.0
- difficulty is relative and really depends on type of test being built. Is customization through scala in Gatling *simple* ?
- do you understand this, I don't :

  - *Apache JMeter supports recording the users’ clicks or actions while testing the web applications where as Gatling also supports the user actions and also any other simulated scenarios.*
- What about those statements :

  - *Apache JMeter is less efficient and effective to be used with odd GUI features that are difficult to use where as Gatling has GUI as well as command line features that provide efficient and effective outputs.*

    => What are odd GUI features ?
    => JMeter is an IDE for test building, Gatling uses the test as code approach
  - *Apache JMeter does not have code scripting facility whereas Gatling has the code scripting facility.* => Does the author know about JSR223 Test Elements ? functions ?
  - *Apache JMeter has more number of lines of code to configure and setup the testing where as Gatling has less number of lines of code to be used in its’ configuration to run the load tests.* => Really ?  what are those ?
  - ...

Comment: Thank you for answering, let's assume the article is evaluating a very old JMeter version